# Simple Isabelle/HOL theory: Inner lexical error⌂ Failed to parse prop

Tags: isabelle, proof

I am trying to create my first Isabelle/HOL theory that encodes Monoidal logic but I am stuck already with the first axiom - identity axiom. I do not understand what is wrong with my code, because error message does not give explanation. My theory is:

```
theory MonoidalLogic
  imports  "~~/src/ZF/Main" Sequents 
begin
consts
  Mult :: "[o, o]⇒o"
axiomatization where
  identity: "P ⊢ P"
 (* and
  cut: "φ⊢ψ;ψ⊢ρ⟹φ⊢ρ" and
  l: "φ⊢⊤⨂ψ⟺φ⊢ψ" and
  r: "φ⊢ψ⨂⊤⟺φ⊢ψ"*)
end
```

Error message is at *identity: "P **⊢ P**"*:

```
Inner lexical error⌂
Failed to parse prop
```

What should I correct to move forward?

*Note added:* I am trying to implement Monoidal logic in similar manner how the Linear logic is implemented in Isabelle/HOL: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/library/Sequents/Sequents/ILL.html And `identity: "P ⊢ P"` is the first axiom for many logics, including Linear logic and Monoidal logic. I am starting to feel that ⊢ is not the first class character for Isabelle but it may be introduced by syntax rule

```
syntax "_Trueprop" :: "single_seqe" ("((_)/ ⊢ (_))" [6,6] 5)
```

in Linear logic. I don' understand this rule but I guess I should introduce something like this in my theory as well...

Comment: The problem is that this turnstile symbol (`⊢`) is not defined anywhere. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I added note that further explains what I am trying to achieve and what is my current guess for the way forward. I am reading LNCS 2283 and LNCS 828 which are books where such shortcuts are explained. But short explanation for faster moving forward can be of help..